# How to handle AJAX requests in EXTJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, sencha-touch-2.3

I have a code to send an AJAX request which seems to work fine under firebug (sending correct parameters) :

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'test',
            params:{name: "bunya"},
            success: function(resp){ 
                    button1.setText(resp.responseText);
                },
            failure: function(e,resp){
                    button1.setText('Disgrace!');
                }
            });
    }
```

Servlet code part (from what i understand) should get name:

```
String respString =request.getAttribute("name").toString();
```

which returns null.

My question is, how can i get the attributes from this application/x-www-form-urlencoded request?

Comment: do u use web service?

Comment: No, i don't. These 2 files and an obvious web.xml is what i have in my project.

Comment: What vesions of ExtJS are you using? version 5 doesn't seem to have a `getAttribute` method.

Comment: Servlet code is in java, and object request is in type HTTPServletRequest

Comment: So your question is about your javaserverlet, rather than extjs, then.

Comment: Yes. Should i add the properties of the sent request to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use request.getParameter("name") for fetching a parameter value. You can use request.getParameterNames() to fetch all parameter names in the current request.